# User-defined strings for cross-program copy / paste

Tags: java, copy, paste

I'm trying to build a program that supplements and replaces Windows shortcuts with those defined by the user. Currently, I'm working on building a copy/paste function, but can't figure out how to move the copied object into a program other than mine. I tried using the Robot class to simulate keypresses depending on the value at a specific index in a string, but that won't allow me to pass variables other than the VKEY constants.

What would be needed in a method to copy and paste text between programs?

Comment: move programmatically, or by the user?

Comment: I'm hoping to paste text when the user presses a hotkey, let's say alt-V for simplicity's sake.

Comment: How do you expect to get (hot)key events. on other than your program?

Comment: The program runs in the background. I'm honestly not sure how this would work, which is why I'm asking here. Would I need an overlay of some sort? Should I set the program to constantly hold focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would consider using JavaFX: There is a Clipboard class, which claims to get the system clipboard, but I haven't tried if it works accross (non-JavaFX) applications:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html

**Edit:**

There is also an AWT-based Clipboard: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html

Comment: I'll look into this. I saw an answer on another question that mentioned that class, but couldn't figure out where the class itself was. (The import wasn't listed,  it just said Clipboard.)

Comment: Update: The AWT Clipboard only functions within the application itself. I've installed JDK7 with JavaFX, but Eclipse won't recognize it. How would I fix this?